# Overriding HTTP client config while declaring routes

Tags: apache-camel, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a web application from which I'm calling around 50-60 rest/soap apis. For this, I've created routes in JAVA DSL. Now, to have default application level timeout settings, I've done configuration like this-

```
public class DefaultHttpClientConfig implements HttpClientConfigurer {   // http4
    @Override 
    public void configureHttpClient(HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder) { 
            clientBuilder.setDefaultRequestConfig( 
                            RequestConfig.custom() 
                                    .setConnectTimeout(1000) 
                                    .setSocketTimeout(1000).build()); 
    } 
}
```

and I've set this in camel context like this-

```
    static CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext(); 

    static { 
            try { 
                    HttpComponent httpComponent = ctx.getComponent("http4", HttpComponent.class); 
                    httpComponent.setConnectionTimeToLive(10); 
                    httpComponent.setHttpClientConfigurer(new DefaultHttpClientConfig()); 
                    ctx.addRoutes(new DirectRestRouteBuilder()); 
                    ctx.start(); 
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
    }
```

Now when creating individual routes, I want to override these configuration, so I'm trying this as shown below-

```
from("direct:success") 
       .to("http4://localhost:8089/mockcarrier/success?httpClient.socketTimeout=8000");
```

However, it seems that the direct configuration in JAVA DSL is not picked up. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add `DefaultHttpClientConfig` to the Camel registry and set it on the route with the `httpClientConfigurer` parameter ([Camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html#HTTP4-ConfiguringApacheHTTPClientDirectly)).

Like this:

```
.to("http4://localhost:8089/mockcarrier/success?httpClientConfigurer=yourCustomConfigurerNameInTheRegistry");
```